# Using CompoundJs with Passport

Tags: node.js, authentication, mongoose, passport.js, compoundjs

I'm trying to use Passport with Compound Js. I've configured the passport in an initialization file. as below

```
var passport = require('passport')
 , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},
      function(email, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: email }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
   }
      return done(null, user);
  });
 }
 ));
 module.exports.passport = passport;
```

And in my routes file I have:

```
var passobj = require('./initializers/initialize_passport')

 exports.routes = function (map) {
       map.post("api/users", passobj.passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:  'user#index', failureRedirect: 'user#failureoccured'}));
 };
```

When I tried to call this from firebug by passing a valid username and password, I get the below error:

```
Undefined action undefined#undefined
```

Can anyone please tell me how to use Passport with Compound Js.

And also I came accross compound-passport, but don't know if I can use it for local strategy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create your passport-local dir?¿¿

Comment: compound-passport has a local strategy implemented. Look in your compound-passport/strategies folder at the local.js, it's pretty straightforward except for a silly len variable used to check how many parameters are supposed to be passed to your verifyPassword function. Put verifyPassword function in your user model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to make my local. Hope you can solve your implementation also this way.

It will create a full new strategy that you will be able to use together

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var config = require('../config/environment');
var User = require('../api/user/user.model');

// Passport Configuration
require('./login/passport').setup(User, config);

//HERE WE  WILL ADD OUR LOCAL STRATEGY
var router = express.Router();
router.use('/local', require('./local/index'));
```

**local/index.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var auth = require('../auth.service.js');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  console.log.req;

  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, "THAT´S BAD");
    if (!user) return res.json(404, {message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});
    var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
    res.json({token: token, user:user});
  })(req, res, next)
});

module.exports = router;
```

**local/passport.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Local = require('passport-local').Strategy;

exports.setup = function (User, config) {
  passport.use("local", new Local({
      usernameField: 'apikey',
      passwordField: 'apisecret'
    },

    function(apikey, apisecret, done) {
//THIS FUNCTION IS THE ONE YOU HAVE TO IMPLEMENT TO YOUR LOCAL WAY
      User.findOne({
        apikey: apikey,
        apisecret: apisecret
      }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          return done("YOUR API KEY HAS NOT AUTHORIZATION", false, { message: 'This email is not registered.' });
        }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done("USER", user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });


};
```